# How to create a Simulink executable which uses .mat file input

Tags: matlab, input, executable, simulink

I have created a gas turbine model on simulink for my final year project for my engineering degree. However I need some help in converting it to a standalone executable, currently the standalone executable uses the inputs that were there when it was compiled. How do I compile an executable which requires a .mat file input?
Regards 
Rajeev

Comment: Are you needing to modify model parameters or model inputs (or both)?  Is the executable for real-time use or simulation?  Will the machine running the executable have MATLAB and Simulink installed on it or not?  The answers to these questions will effect the method you need to use.

Comment: Hi Phil, thank you for replying. I will be modifying both, the executable is for simulation and will be running on a machine without MATLAB or simulink. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Generate C-Code from your existing simulink model by using
   an additional toolbox: [Simulink Coder](https://de.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ug/generate-c-code-from-simulink-model.html).
2. To read from (or write to) Mat-File you can use [C-API to Mat-File](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-c-api-to-read-mat-file-data.html). You will find the sources in:
   *"your Matlab - Installation - Folder"/extern/examples/eng_mat*
3. In the generated c-Code you will find a structure representing the inports of your model. Write the corresponding value you read from the matfile to in port. You will probably need a loop of call for MdlInputs, MdlUpdate, MdlOutputs (implementation of these 3 functions are also generated ) to run the simulation. A good starting example is the *main.c of the grt-Target *("your Matlab - Installation - Folder"/rtw/c/grt)*.